# memo doesn't detect the changes in the props pass into the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I'm using the `useMutation` hook from Apollo GraphQL and I want perform a certain task using the `onCompleted` property. Bascially, I want to execute the `setCheck()` hook when the `useMutation` is successfully completed and pass the `check` state as a prop to the child component

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [ check, setCheck ] = useState(false)
    const [ createMessage, { loading } ] = useMutation(CREATE_MESSAGE_MUTATION, {
        onCompleted: data => {
            setCheck(true)
        },
        onError: data => {
            console.log("onError Mutation", data)
        }
    })

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
            <FlatList 
                data={messages}
                renderItem={({ item }) => 
                    <ChildComponent 
                        item={item} 
                        check={check}
                    />
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}
```

The problem is that the `ChildComponent` renders way too many times every time the parent component renders so I used `memo` which solved the unnecessary re-rendering:

```js
const ChildComponent = ({check}) => {
    console.log("check", check)
    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >

        </View>
    )
}

export default React.memo(ChildComponent)
```

But, `memo` somehow doesn't detect the change in the state `check` and doesn't render the component at all. Why does `memo` fail to detail the changes in the props passed in and is there a way to listen to the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `FlatList` - it only re-renders its children when its `data` changes. Since `renderItem` depends on `check` which is not part of `data` you need to include it in the `extraData` prop to cause the items to re-render when `check` changes. See the docs for an example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#basic-example

So your `FlatList` component should be:

```
            <FlatList 
                data={messages}
                renderItem={({ item }) => 
                    <ChildComponent 
                        item={item} 
                        check={check}
                    />
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                extraData={check}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

`check` is not a part of the state, it is part of the props. try to pass it to a `useState` hook to make the component stateful